# Css select first child inside another childs

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to select the first child inside some other elements.
This is the example.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="feature">
  <div class="some"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="feature">
  <div class="some"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="feature">
  <div class="required">I NEED TO SELECT THIS</div>
 </div>
 <div class="feature">
  <div class="required">NOT THIS</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to select first occurrence of required. And also there can be arbitrary numbers div with .feature ( with .some) before i get to div which contains .required .

Can this be done ?

What i tried. (not working)

```
.parent .required:first-child {}
.parent .required:first-of-type {}
```

Comment: You can try .parent > .required which will select all .required under .parent class and than you can undo this for all except the first .required class with .parent > .required ~ .required . You can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: @JureVidmar thanks ! I did go through that thread. But It seems to be mostly for direct children under parent. I did try .parent > .required ~ .required, but it does not work.

Comment: Im not sure if its possible with css, but with javascript it is. "document.querySelector('.parent  .feature .required');" will fetch the first occurrence and then you can assign any class to it.

Comment: Thanks ! will use JavaScript, if this is not possible in CSS.

Comment: @Martin thanks ! I tried the above, but it selects both of them. Instead of the first .required.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the nesting. In that case it can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent .feature .required:first-child {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="feature">
       <div class="some"></div>
     </div>
   <div class="feature">
     <div class="some"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="feature">
    <div class="required">I NEED TO SELECT THIS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="feature">
   <div class="required">NOT THIS</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i need to select first occurrence of .required. I have updated the question.

Comment: This doesn't work for what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a separate `class` for this. `.parent .feature .required:first-child` will work for the first childs of `required` `class`. In your code `<div class="required">I NEED TO SELECT THIS</div>` and `<div class="required">NOT THIS</div>` both are first childs of `.parent` `class.`
So if you have at least two child of class then following works.

```css
.parent .feature .required:first-child {
            color:red;

        }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="some"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="some"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="required">I NEED TO SELECT THIS (First child)</div>
                <div class="required">NOT THIS(second child)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="required">NOT THIS (This is also first child)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Hope you will understand the problem.

Comment: You can define different hierarchies according to your requirements.

Comment: There is no second .required in the same .feature div.